# Filtering nested array of objects by array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, mapping, filtering

Good evening

Wondering if anyone could give me hand, I seem to be going in circles
I am trying to get all the objects containing the `key/field` `"type"` from an array, by another array of strings.

```
{
  "someData": [
    {
      "date": "someDate",
      "someNestedData": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "type": "type1",
          "dateCreated": "someDate"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "type": "type2",
          "dateCreated": "someDate"
        }
      ]
    },
      {
      "date": "someDate",
      "someNestedData": [
        {
          "id": "3",
          "type": "type1",
          "dateCreated": "someDate"
        },
        {
          "id": "4",
          "type": "type4",
          "dateCreated": "someDate"
        }
      ]
    }

  ]
}
```

and another array of strings `const types = ['type1', 'type2`]`
I am trying to filter out the array so that any object not containing the key in the types array is filtered out.

So the end result would be

```
{
  "someData": [
    {
      "date": "someDate",
      "someNestedData": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "type": "type1",
          "dateCreated": "someDate"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "type": "type2",
          "dateCreated": "someDate"
        }
      ]
    },
      {
      "date": "someDate",
      "someNestedData": [
        {
          "id": "3",
          "type": "type1",
          "dateCreated": "someDate"
        },
      ]
    }

  ]
}
```

I have tried something along the lines of

```
data.someData.someNestedData.indexOf(function (i) {
  return types.indexOf(i.type);
})
```

as well as a few other bloated approaches, just not coming right and looking for something quite performant.
TIA :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
const types = ['type1', 'type2'];
const res = [
    {
      "date": "someDate",
      "someNestedData": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "type": "type1",
          "dateCreated": "someDate"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "type": "type2",
          "dateCreated": "someDate"
        }
      ]
    },
      {
      "date": "someDate",
      "someNestedData": [
        {
          "id": "3",
          "type": "type1",
          "dateCreated": "someDate"
        },
        {
          "id": "4",
          "type": "type4",
          "dateCreated": "someDate"
        }
      ]
    }
]
// map over the array
.map(obj => ({
     // rebuild the object 
     ...obj, 
     // but replace "someNestedData" with the list of element that has the 'type' filed included in types
     someNestedData: obj.someNestedData.filter(
          el => types.includes(el.type)
     )
}))
console.log(res)
```